# mysql UPDATE with out specifying the column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update all values in my table irrespective of column where the value matches to a particular value

eg:

Table
    column_a         column_b        column_c

```
abc              xhk             None
None             thk             hi
xyz              None            None
None             abcdef          None
```

I want to change all **'None'** to **'N/A'**

Desired result table
    column_a         column_b        column_c

```
abc              xhk             N/A
N/A              thk             hi
xyz              N/A             N/A
N/A              abcdef          N/A
```

I can do this with queries

```
update table_name set column_a = 'N/A' where column_a = 'None'
update table_name set column_b = 'N/A' where column_b = 'None'
update table_name set column_c = 'N/A' where column_c = 'None'
```

Is there a better way to do this, preferably without specifying column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a suggestion. I Thought it can be like this. If it's working. Let me know.

```
$SqlQuery = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM TableName";
    $Result= mysql_query($SqlQuery);
    while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {
      $ColumnName=$Row['Field'];
      mysql_query("UPDATE TableName SET $ColumnName='N/A' WHERE $ColumnName='None'");
    }
```

Comment: I like the idea, I'd probably build the SQL statement up in the while loop, so you only hit the database once, but for each column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Dynamic SQL

```
set @sql:='';
select @sql:=concat(@sql,' case when ',column_name,'=''none'' 
     then ''N/A'' else ',column_name,' end,');
set @sql:=left(@sql,length(@sql)-1);
set @sql:=concat('select ',@sql,' from your_table');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: I was looking for a method which doesn't require use of column names, ie, if there are a lot of columns, query just grows in size right? Is there a more generic way to do this?